# Include HTML in Shiny - tabPanel doens't change size

Tags: html, r, shiny, shinydashboard

I'm working on a dashboard in Shiny and I would like to include some images (and be able to position them on the page. However, the box in which I included some text and images doesn't have any height. Does anyone know how to fix this? I've included my code and a screenshot of my dashboard.

My code (UI) (The problem is in Tab4):

```
dashboardBody(    
    useShinyjs(),
    fluidRow(
        tabBox(
            side = 'right',
            width = 12,
            height = "100%",
            selected = "Tab1",
            tabPanel("Tab1", 
                dataTableOutput('table2')),
            tabPanel("Tab2", 
                dataTableOutput('table1')),
            tabPanel("Tab3", 
                h2("Old:"),
                h4("some text to explain the datatable"),
                DT::dataTableOutput('table3'),
                hr(),
                h2("New:"),
                h4("Some more text to explain this datatable."),
                DT::dataTableOutput('table4')
              ),
            tabPanel("Tab4", 
                div(h2("This is an example"),
                    p("some text"),
                    h3("some header"),
                    p('Even more text'),
                    img(src='logoStackOverflow.PNG'),
                    p('explain something about the image'),
                    style ="position:absolute;
                    max-width:1200px;
                    left:30px;
                    top:40px;
                    height:100%;"),
                div(img(src="logoStackOverflow.PNG"),
                    img(src="logoStackOverflow.PNG"),
                    style ="position:absolute;
                            border: 1px solid;
                            max-width:300px;
                            box-align:right;
                            position: fixed;
                            height:auto;
                            right:100px;
                            top:150px;")
             )
          )
         )
        )
```

[image: Screenshot of my Shiny dashboard]

Answer (score 0):

You were very close.  Replace `img()` with `tags$img()` and provide height and width as `tags$img(height=100, width=100, src="YBS.png", style="text-align: right;")`.  Then you get the following [output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BA8g6.png) in tab4.